# Is it possible to write a bot that repeats all messages of a specific group member?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

So that whenever my group member Bob writes a message, the bot immediatly copies it (echoing him)?

Comment: Your question is not specific. The answer is yes: your robot can receive messages in a group and can send messages to the group and it means it can repeat messages in the group.

Comment: But can the Bot receive ALL messages or just those explicitly for him (by / or smth)?

Comment: If the bot is allowed to access messages in the group, it can receive any messages when the message is sent by user.